# JavaScript windows.onload or referencing new elements?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to create a lightbox and I'm having trouble.

I think the problem is either because I have 2 window.onloads or because I'm trying to reference a newly created DOM element. I added some comments in the code below that explain what I'm trying to do.

```
//open lightbox
window.onload = showLargeImage;

function showLargeImage() {
    var enlargeButton = document.getElementById("thumb1"); // thumb1 is a thumbnail you click to get the lightbox
    enlargeButton.onclick = handleClick;
}

function handleClick() {
    var lightboxContainerId = document.getElementById("lightboxContainer");
    lightboxContainerId.innerHTML = '<div class="lightbox"><a class="reduceButton" href="#" ><img id="imageButton" class="largeImage" src="2012/images/web/web1.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="Web Thumb 1"></a></div>';
} // the inner HTML creates the lightbox.

//close lightbox
window.onload = reduceImage; // i'm pretty sure that this windo.onload is the problem... or, that I'm referencing "imageButton" which is new to the DOM             

function reduceImage() {
    var reduceButton = document.getElementById("imageButton"); // you're supposed to click the big image in the lightbox to get close it.  
    reduceButton.onclick = handleReduceClick;
}

function handleReduceClick() {
    var shadeId = document.getElementById("lightboxContainer");
    shadeId.innerHTML = "say what"; // closing the lightbox simply strips everything out of the lightboxContainer                
    alert("oh yeah");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few reasons why your code is not working:

- showLargeImage and reduceImage are missing invocation parentheses in the places where they are being assigned to window.onload. Without parentheses, window.onload is being assigned a function, but that function is not getting called. You should, for instance, have window.onload = showLargeImage();
- As you suspected, the second window.onload is overwriting the first.
- reduceButton is (as you also suspected) being assigned before it exists, causing an error.

Here is one solution that may work for you.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title></title>
</head><body>

    <a href="#" id="thumb">View</a>
    <div id="lightboxcontainer"></div>

</body></html>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {

    // click link to show
    var enlargeButton = document.getElementById('thumb');
    enlargeButton.onclick = function() {
        var lightboxContainerId = document.getElementById('lightboxcontainer');
        lightboxContainerId.innerHTML = '<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"' +
                                        'width="350" height="150 alt="Thumb 1">' +
                                        '<p>Click image to hide.</p>';
    };

    // click image to hide
    var reduceButton = document.getElementById('lightboxcontainer');
    reduceButton.onclick = function() {
        reduceButton.innerHTML = ''; // removes lightbox contents         
    };
};
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ericmathison/BxwYY/7/

Answer (score 0):

If the code is placed at the end of the `<body>` (or anywhere after your lightbox elements), just use this:

```
document.getElementById("thumb1").onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("lightboxContainer").innerHTML = '<div class="lightbox"><a class="reduceButton" href="#" ><img id="imageButton" class="largeImage" src="2012/images/web/web1.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt="Web Thumb 1"></a></div>';  
    document.getElementById("imageButton").onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById("lightboxContainer").innerHTML = "say what";
        alert("oh yeah");
    };
}
```

This will do everything you want.